# Google Cloud Compute Engine not Migrated Before Power off (Maintenance?)

Tags: google-compute-engine

I was under the impression according to docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options) that if your VM was set to "Migrate VM Instance" for "on host maintenance" there would be no downtime.

I have 2 issues:

1) I had a VM go down this weekend and here is what the auth.log shows:

```
Sep 10 20:28:07 comp_engine_name systemd-logind[2571]: Power key pressed.
Sep 10 20:28:07 comp_engine_name systemd-logind[2571]: Powering Off...
Sep 10 20:28:07 comp_engine_name systemd-logind[2571]: System is powering down.
Sep 10 20:28:07 comp_engine_name sshd[3291]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Sep 10 20:28:07 comp_engine_name systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user username
```

My Google cloud platform logs for Compute Engine show that at 20:28, my instance received a "GCE_API_CALL" event type for "compute.instances.stop."  The user for this event was "".  So not very helpful.

2) The instance was not automatically restarted.

Here is a screenshot of my relevant settings for this VM. [image] 
I did not shut it down myself, and there are no scripts running on it that controls power/restart.  I also do not see evidence that my security was compromised (although I admit I'm not an expert).

**Am I wrong or should neither of these things happened?**

Comment: Is the instance part of a managed instance group with auto-scaling?

Comment: @Dagang, No it is just a standalone VM